# Boy's dream about a hairy monster or alien turns out to be real

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

What is this 1950s sci-fi movie about a boy's dream?

I remember its ending where you are convinced that all the action in the movie turns out to just be a dream that occurred when a boy fell asleep at a picnic with his family. But then some kind of large hairy monster/alien comes out of a cave and you know that it really wasn't a dream.

Comment: I DON'T think this is a duplicate of http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13631/identify-a-1950s-sci-fi-movie.  Can the merge be undone?

Comment: @WillFeldman If you think so, flag it for moderator attention or maybe post a meta question.

Comment: @WillFeldman hey how you got sure that they both are separate? The other one just looks like its remaining part.

Comment: @michale can you clarify that both question are same or different ?

Comment: I think they are separate because in this question he lists several things he remembers about the movie.  In the other question he says "I just recall the ending."  Also, the other question matches the movie "Robot Monster", and this question does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely [Robot Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Monster), (1953).

> Ultimately the youngest family member, the son, wakes up after
>   suffering a mild concussion, revealing that the film had presumably
>   all been a dream. However, The Great Guidance is then seen coming out
>   of a cave (three times in a row).

The monster was hairy:

> The budget did not allow for a robot costume as intended so Tucker
>   used his friend George Barrows who had his own gorilla suit to play
>   Ro-Man. Tucker added the helmet.

Comment: This answer was for "I just recall the ending... where you are convinced all the action in the movie turns out to just be a dream while a boy fell asleep at a picnic with his family and then some kind of large harry monster/alien comes out of a cave and you are left knowing it really wasn't a dream."  I don't think it should have been merged here.

Comment: I don't think that a merge can be undone - sorry - it had been flagged as a duplicate and it did look like it.  My apologies.  I can re-open the other question and you can repost this answer, and I will upvote it to help restore the lost rep.

Comment: I have re-opened it - but it still gets marked as a merged duplicate.

Comment: @iandotkelly reopening doesn't solved the problem yet. Because this answer doesn't belongs to this question.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I know that. I could try a merge the other way, but I would do so in the understanding that I don't know whether it will end up as we would expect.   I suggested above that Will just re-answers in the other question.  This might just be the easiest.

Comment: @iandotkelly other question is not answerable anymore.

Comment: Will Feldman you got it right- Robot Monster.